# Re-resolve remote AD's ip address when using OpenLDAP as proxy to AD

Tags: proxy, openldap

It is working when setting up OpenLDAP as proxy to AD. However after certain time, the OpenLdap proxy is unable to reach AD unless OpenLdap proxy is restarted.

I suspect that OpenLdap proxy caches remote LDAP IP address, and could not reach AD once IP is changed or AD is under round robin schedule.

Is there a way to force Open Ldap proxy to re-resolve remote AD naming?